# how stop html5 video when bootstrap modal is closed and replay again when click play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have a page with three html5 videos that I want to be played in a  popup modal when the user click that 'play' button.I have three modal with three id,like myModal1,myModal2,and myModal3!and video file comes from server dynamically. I searched and tried many solutions but have not found one which works correctly for me! Does anybody have an idea of a solution for my problem which will allow:

- when user click on a play button, that specific bootstrap modal video loads and plays.
- when user closes the modal, the video will stop.
- when user re-selects a video it could be played again.

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
  $('.winnr-ply').on('click', function(){
 var video = document.getElementById('lotto');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src', 'video/v3.mp4');

video.appendChild(source);
video.play();

$(".close").click(function() {  
    video.pause();

   source.setAttribute('src', ''); 



}, 3000); 
 });

 
});

</script>
```

```html
<button class="winnr-ply winner-videos"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">play video</button>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-dialog my-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content winner-v">
                              <div class="modal-header lg-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body lg-body">
                                    <video id="video1" width="500px" height="400px" controls >
                                     <source src="video/v3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    </video>
                              </div>
                              
                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code sample has three video buttons, and loads each video into the same Bootstrap Modal after setting the source. It uses the Bootstrap shown/hide events to trigger Play and Pause when the modal is activated/hidden.

If you wanted you could store the position of each video when closing the modal and re-seeking to that point if it's opened (would need an array to hold each position for each video so that gets a bit more complex, but not a huge effort - the question just said re-played, didn't say if you wanted to continue to play from the same position)

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Videos</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="modal('v1.mp4')">Video One</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="modal('v2.mp4')">Video Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="modal('v3.mp4')">Video Three</button>

<script>
//  attach the events to the modal
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
      document.getElementById("video").pause(); 
      console.log("Video paused");
    });
    $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      document.getElementById("video").play(); 
      console.log("Video play");
    });
});

// this will load the video source and show the modal programmatically
function modal(v){
    document.getElementById("video").src = v
    $("#myModal").modal()
}
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Video</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <video id="video" controls >
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

this code sample has three buttons, but rather than sharing a model window and injecting the video source into it, each button triggers a different modal window which has the relevant video source. Video Play and Pause for each of the modal windows are controlled in the event for the relevant myModal1/myModal2/myModal3 div/id

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Videos</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Video One</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Video Two</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Video Three</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal1").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video1").pause(); 
       console.log("Video1 paused");
    });
    $("#myModal1").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video1").play(); 
       console.log("Video1 play");
    });

    $("#myModal2").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video2").pause(); 
       console.log("Video2 paused");
    });
    $("#myModal2").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video2").play(); 
       console.log("Video2 play");
    });

    $("#myModal3").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video3").pause(); 
       console.log("Video3 paused");
    });
    $("#myModal3").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       document.getElementById("video3").play(); 
       console.log("Video3 play");
    });
});

</script>

  <!-- Modal #1-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Video1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video id="video1" controls>
              <source src="BigBuck.m4v">
          </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal #2-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Video2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video id="video2" controls>
              <source src="BigBuck.m4v">
          </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal #3-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Video3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <video id="video3" controls>
              <source src="BigBuck.m4v">
          </video>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much!I repalce my code with yours but it doesn't work for me ! i don't know why $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () or  $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () doesnt work for me ?! when I close modal video still is playing in background! im confused !

Comment: i have three buttons which thode data-target is set wth three modals id .so i have three modal ids like myModal1,myModal2,myModal3.

Comment: re video still playing: is the `ID` of your modal `myModal`? if not then the function won't attach to the right place. Does the video play automatically when the modal opens?

Comment: re three buttons: do you want to use a single modal, or do you want three different modal pop-ups defined and have each button assigned to a specific modal?

Comment: I have three deferent modal and three buttons.but buttons haven't ID ,they set with modal with data-target.

Comment: see second example in the answer above, splits the buttons so they each have their own modal (makes for more code to maintain, so wouldn't be my prefered option). Tested using Bootstrap 3.3.7